# Win check conditions Connect 4 (Java)

Tags: java, algorithm, methods

I've been struggling with getting my win checker methods to work for my Connect4 code. My "work" I mean the game doesn't recognize a win configuration and will only end when all spaces are filled

I think there's something wrong with my algorithm, so I'm sure if I can figure out what's wrong with one of them then I should be able to fix all of them.

I want these methods to return a boolean value which will state whether someone has won or not.

Here's my full code:

```
public class ConnectFour
{
    private static int rowMax = 7;
    private static int colMax = 8;
private static String boardFill = "| |";

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String playerX = choosePlayerName("X").toUpperCase();
    String playerO = choosePlayerName("O").toUpperCase();
    String[][] players = {{playerX, playerO},{"X","O"}};

    String endChoice;
    do
    {
        int playerTurn = pickFirstPlayer(players);

        String board[][] = createBoard(rowMax, colMax, boardFill);  
        printBoard(board);

        int turnCount = 0;
        boolean gameOver = false;
        while (gameOver == false) 
        {
            showPlayerTurn(players, playerTurn);

            int rowChosen = -1;
            int colChosen = -1;
            do
            {
                colChosen = chooseCol(colMax);
                rowChosen = findRowIndex(board, colChosen);
            }
            while (isValidMove(board, rowChosen) == false);

            board[rowChosen][colChosen] = ("|"+players[1][playerTurn]+"|");
            printBoard(board);

            playerTurn = changePlayerTurn(playerTurn);
            turnCount++;

            gameOver = checkWinRows(board, rowMax, colMax);
            gameOver = checkWinVertical(board, rowMax, colMax);
            gameOver = checkWinFSlash(board, rowMax, colMax);
            gameOver = checkWinBSlash(board, rowMax, colMax);
            gameOver = checkMaxTurnCount(turnCount, rowMax, colMax);

        }

        if (checkMaxTurnCount(turnCount, rowMax, colMax))
        {
            System.out.println("\n\nMaximum number of moves reached, it's a draw.");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("\nPlayer"+players[0][playerTurn]+" Wins!");
        }
        endChoice = checkQuitOrRestart().toUpperCase(); 
        endQuit(endChoice);
    }
    while (endChoice.equals("R"));
}

// Player Instantiate Methods
public static String choosePlayerName(String playerSymbol) 
{

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner nameInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("\nYour Symbol is "+playerSymbol+". Please Enter Player's Name: ");
    String playerName = nameInput.nextLine();

    return playerName;
}
public static int pickFirstPlayer(String[][] players)
{
    return (int) Math.round(Math.random());

}
// Board Create/Print Methods   
public static String[][] createBoard(int rowMax, int colMax, String boardFill)
{
    {
        String board[][] = new String[rowMax][colMax];

        for (int row = 0; row < rowMax; row++) 
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < colMax; col++) 
            {
                board[row][col] = boardFill;
            }
        }
        return board;
    }
}
public static void printBoard(String[][] board)
{
    System.out.print("\n 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8");
    for (int row = 0; row < rowMax; row++)
    {
        System.out.print("\n");
        for (int col = 0; col < colMax; col++)
        {
            System.out.print(board[row][col]);          
        }
    }
}
// Player Turn Methods
public static void showPlayerTurn(String players[][], int playerTurn)
{
    System.out.println("\nPlayer's Turn: "+players[0][playerTurn]+" ["+players[1][playerTurn]+"]");
}
public static int chooseCol(int colMax)
{
    boolean isColValid;
    int colChosen = -1;

    do
    {
        isColValid = true;
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner colInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Choose a column to place your token [1-8]: ");
        try 
        {
            colChosen = colInput.nextInt();
            if (colChosen < 1 || colChosen > colMax) 
            {
                isColValid = false;
                System.out.println("Column out of bounds.");
            }
        } 
        catch (NumberFormatException e) 
        {
            isColValid = false;
            System.out.println("Enter valid number");
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e)
        {
            isColValid = false;
            System.out.println("Enter column number as integer.");
        }
    }
    while (!isColValid);

    return (colChosen - 1);
}
public static int findRowIndex(String[][] board, int colChosen)
{
    int rowChosen = -1;

    for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < board.length; rowIndex++)
    {
        if (board[rowIndex][colChosen] == boardFill)
        {
            rowChosen = rowIndex;
        }
    }

    return rowChosen;
}
public static boolean isValidMove(String[][] board, int rowChosen)
{
    boolean validMove;

    if (rowChosen == -1)
    {
        System.out.print("Column full, please select valid column.");
        validMove = false;
    }
    else
    {
        validMove = true;
    }

    return validMove;
}
public static int changePlayerTurn(int playerTurn)
{
    if (playerTurn == 0)
    {
        playerTurn = 1;
    }
    else if (playerTurn ==1)
    {
        playerTurn = 0;
    }

    return playerTurn;
}
// Win/End Condition Check Methods
// Win Check Methods    
public static boolean checkWinRows(String[][] board, int rowMax, int colMax)
{
    boolean winRowCheck = false;

    for (int row = 0; row < rowMax; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < (colMax - 3); col++)
        {
            if (board[row][col] == board[row][col + 1] &&
                    board[row][col] == board[row][col + 2] &&
                    board[row][col] == board[row][col + 3] &&
                    board[row][col] != "| |")
            {
                winRowCheck = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return winRowCheck;
}
public static boolean checkWinVertical(String[][] board, int rowMax, int colMax)
{
    boolean winVerticalCheck = false;

    for (int row = 0; row < (rowMax - 3); row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < (colMax - 3); col++)
        {
            if (board[row][col] == board[row + 1][col] &&
                    board[row][col] == board[row + 2][col] &&
                    board[row][col] == board[row + 3][col] &&
                    board[row][col] != "| |")
            {
                winVerticalCheck = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return winVerticalCheck;
}
public static boolean checkWinFSlash(String[][] board, int rowMax, int colMax)
{
    Boolean winFSlashCheck = false;

    for (int row = 3; row < rowMax; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < (colMax - 3); col++)
        {
            if (board[row][col] == board[row - 1][col + 1] &&
                    board[row][col] == board[row - 2][col + 2] &&
                    board[row][col] == board[row - 3][col + 3] &&
                    board[row][col] != "| |")
            {
                winFSlashCheck = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return winFSlashCheck;
}
public static boolean checkWinBSlash(String[][] board, int rowMax, int colMax)
{
    boolean winBSlash = false;

    for (int row = 4; row < rowMax; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 3; col < (colMax - 3); col++)
        {
            if (board[row][col] == board[row - 1][col - 1] &&
                    board[row][col] == board[row - 1][col - 2] &&
                    board[row][col] == board[row - 1][col - 3] &&
                    board[row][col] != "| |")
            {
                winBSlash = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return winBSlash;
}
public static boolean checkMaxTurnCount(int turnCount, int rowMax, int colMax)
{
    boolean maxTurnCountReached = false;

    if (turnCount >= rowMax*colMax)
    {
        maxTurnCountReached = true;
    }

    return maxTurnCountReached;
}
// End Prompt Methods   
// End Game Methods 
public static String checkQuitOrRestart()
{
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner endChoiceImport = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("\nPlease Select: Restart [R] or Quit [Q]");
    String endChoice = endChoiceImport.next();

    return endChoice;
}
public static void endQuit(String endChoice)
{
    if (endChoice.equals("Q") || endChoice.equals("q"))
    {
        System.out.println("\nQuitting Program.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    else if (endChoice.equals("R"))
    {
        System.out.println("\nRestarting Program.");
    }
}
```

Here's one of the methods (checkWinRows):

```
public static boolean checkWinRows(String[][] board, int rowMax, int colMax)
{
    boolean winRowCheck = false;

    for (int row = 0; row < rowMax; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < (colMax - 3); col++)
        {
            if (board[row][col] == board[row][col + 1] &&
                    board[row][col] == board[row][col + 2] &&
                    board[row][col] == board[row][col + 3] &&
                    board[row][col] != "| |")
            {
                winRowCheck = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return winRowCheck;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `Strings` need to be compared using the `equals` method, otherwise you will compare their references instead of their content.

For example, the `if` statement in `checkWinRows` would look like this:

```
if ((board[row][col].equals(board[row + 1][col]))
    && (board[row][col].equals(board[row + 2][col]))
    && (board[row][col].equals(board[row + 3][col]))
    && (!board[row][col].equals("| |"))) {
    winVerticalCheck = true;
}
```

Then, when you are checking for the `gameOver`, the variable is overwritten by the subsequent methods. You could avoid this using a simple check like this:

```
gameOver = checkWinRows(board, rowMax, colMax);
if(!gameOver) {
    gameOver = checkWinVertical(board, rowMax, colMax);
}
if(!gameOver) {
    gameOver = checkWinFSlash(board, rowMax, colMax);
}
...
```

I didn't look at the whole source so there might be other errors or details you could optimize/improve (for example you could immediately `return true` when you find a win instead of always completing the whole cycle), but this should be enough for you to go on your own.

Also remember to always use a debugger when the program is not behaving as you would expect, it is really a fundamental tool. IDEs like Eclipse always have one integrated that you can easily use.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you compare strings using `==`. This does not work here, since filled cells are not compile time constants, but concatenated at runtime in the following line:

```
board[rowChosen][colChosen] = ("|"+players[1][playerTurn]+"|");
```

Furthermore you overwrite the value of `gameOver` regardless of previous checks.

The latter can be fixed by using a disjunction, the former using `equals` to compare the values.

```
gameOver = checkWinRows(board, rowMax, colMax)
           || checkWinVertical(board, rowMax, colMax)
           || checkWinFSlash(board, rowMax, colMax)
           || checkWinBSlash(board, rowMax, colMax)
           || checkMaxTurnCount(turnCount, rowMax, colMax);
```

```
public static boolean checkWinRows(String[][] board, int rowMax, int colMax)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < rowMax; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < (colMax - 3); col++)
        {
            if (board[row][col] != boardFill && // this references the same object, if it's there, therefore != can be used here
                board[row][col].equals(board[row][col + 1]) &&
                board[row][col].equals(board[row][col + 2]) &&
                board[row][col].equals(board[row][col + 3]))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```